# Let $f$ be a surjective homomorphism. Prove that $\ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, abstract-algebra

Let $f:R\to S$ be a surjective homomorphism, where $R$ is a commutative ring and $S$ is a field. Prove that $\ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal.

I already know that $\ker(f)$ is an ideal of $R$. I tried to consider some ideal $J$ of $R$ such that $\ker(f) \subset J$. If we can show that for arbitrary $y\in J$, $f(y)=0$ then we are good. But I don't know how to show that. Specifically, how does being surjective come into play?

Another theorem I know is that if $f$ is a surjective homomorphism, then quotient ring $R/\ker(f)$ is isomorphic to $S$. Don't know if that's gonna help.

Comment: This is false if $S$ is not a field: take the natural projection $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$. The kernel is $(6)$, but this ideal is not maximal, since it's contained in $(2)$, a proper ideal.

Comment: Is $S$ a field?

Comment: Indeed this is not true if $S$ is not a field, for example $k[x,y]\rightarrow k[x,y]/(xy)$ is surjective, but $(xy)\subset k[x,y]$ is not even prime, so cannot be maximal.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Yes it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An “elementwise” proof. Let $J$ be an ideal properly containing $\ker f$ and take $x\in J$, $x\notin \ker f$.

Then $f(x)\ne0$, so it is invertible, because $S$ is a field. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $y\in R$ such that $f(y)=(f(x))^{-1}$ or, in other words,
$$
f(xy)=1=f(1).
$$
Therefore $t=xy-1\in\ker f$ and so
$$
1=xy-t\in J
$$
(because $x\in J$ and $t\in\ker f\subset J$) which means $J=R$.

A more conceptual proof uses the homomorphism theorems: if $f\colon R\to S$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $f$ induces a bijection between the ideals of $R$ containing $\ker f$ and the ideals of $S$; such a bijection preserves inclusion
(as it is defined by means of the direct image under $f$). If $S$ is a field, it has just the trivial ideals $\{0\}$ and $S$, so there is only one ideal in $R$ properly containing $\ker f$ and so $\ker f$ is maximal.

Comment: Hi @egreg, just wondering where I might find a proof of this: "if f:R→S is a surjective homomorphism, then f induces a bijection between the ideals of R containing kerf and the ideals of S"?

Comment: @jimbobeanz If $\mathcal{R}_f$ is the set of ideals of $R$ containing $\ker f$ and $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of ideals of $S$, the bijections are defined by $I\in\mathcal{R}_f\mapsto f(I)$ and $J\in\mathcal{S}\mapsto f^{-1}(J)$. It's in every algebra book.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. It wasn't stated that $R$ is a field or that $R$ has a unity. How can you conclude that $f(xy)=f(1)$ from $f(xy)=1$? Is there a rule that says if a ring is epimorphic onto a field then that ring must contain a unity element?

Comment: @NicholasCousar I used nowhere that $R$ is a field. But, yes, I assumed that $R$ is a ring with unity, which is the common assumption when doing commutative algebra (unless otherwise stated).

Comment: Good to know. I thought I was going out of my mind haha.

Answer (score 5):

Since $R/\ker(f)$ is a field, $\ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: I think this statement probably also had to be proved.

Comment: Fields have exactly two ideals. QED

Comment: That's probably not clear to someone who's just been introduced to rings.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, the quotient $R / \text{ker}(f)$ is isomorphic to $S$, hence a field.

It remains to show that if $I \subset R$ has the property that $R/I$ is a field, then $I$ must be a maximal ideal. To see this, argue by contradiction. Suppose $I$ is *not* maximal; then there exists an ideal $I \subset J \subset R$ with $J \neq I$ and $J \neq R$. Let $a \in J$, $a \not\in I$. Since $R/I$ is a field, there exists $b \in R$ with $ab = 1 \mod J$. Since $a \in J$ we find that $1 \in J$, contradicting $J \neq R$.

Comment: Why contradiction? Direct proof is better and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\'$ be a ring homomorphism. Then $R/Ker \Phi$ is isomorphic to $\Phi (R)$. Since $\Phi (R)$ is onto and $\mathbb{R}'$ is a field, then $\mathbb{R}/Ker \Phi$ is also a field. Let $\mathbb{R}$ be a commutative ring with unity. Since $\mathbb{R}/Ker \Phi$ is a field, then $Ker \Phi$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}$.

Any comment on my proof? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, we have quite good Latex support here. Type in `$\mathbb{R}$` and you will get $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Okay thanks. But is my proof correct?

Comment: I don't know, my skills are quite elemental in group theory, I am only trying to help others knowing more than me, but lesser the software. Typically, answers to old questions get only few prompt reactions, simply because the topic is old. I hope, others with more skills will see your post and check it.

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much

Comment: I suggest to write many answers, so you will get so many reactions (and upvotes) that you won't have time to process them all. And, if you click the "community wiki" checkbox on post, you give up the reputation what you would get by the upvotes.

Comment: You've got a downvote, it happened probably because you did not use Latex format and our eyes accustomed to that. I made a partial Latex conversion of your answer. I suggest to write more answers, hardcore math people is very welcomed here, and if you write a posts, also your other posts attract more attention.