# If $A$ is isomorphic to $B$ and $B$ is a field, then $A$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a follow-up question to [Let $f$ be a surjective homomorphism. Prove that $\ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064003/f-be-a-surjective-homomorphism-prove-that-kerf-is-the-maximal-ideal). In that question, we know that since $S$ is a field and $R/\ker(f)$ is isomorphic to $S$ then $R/\ker(f)$ is also a field.

More generally, can we loose the condition from being isomorphic to being homomorphic?

Also, suppose $A$ is isomorphic to something weaker than a field, say a group, or an integral domain, is it possible that $A$ is actually a field?

Comment: I am not sure how the title of this question relates to its content, which doesn't make much sense...

Comment: The definition of a Homomorphism (Isomorphism, etc) is given between e.g. Groups, Fields, etc.
So  e.g. the structure preserving map $f: A \rightarrow B$ is called a Field Homomorphism (Isomorphism, etc) only if $A$ and $B$ are both Fields to begin with. 

Therefore, the title is a bit misleading, because the fact that $B$ is a Field already follows directly from the assumption of $A$ being isomorphic to $B$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing that seems to confuse you is that the terminology "A is isomorphic to B" does not mean anything until you specify *as what* they are isomorphic.

For instance, it could be the case that A and B are both groups and that there is a bijective map $\varphi:A\to B$ that is a morphism of groups. In that case, they are isomorphic *as groups*.  This implies that if $A$ has any special property that a group could have, for instance $A$ is abelian or $A$ has only elements of order 2, then B must share that same property.

Now if A and B are both rings and there exist a morphism of rings between A and B then they are isomorphic rings. This implies that any special ring-theoretical property that A may have, must be shared by B. Being a field is actually such a special ring theoretical property, it could be expressed by the statement
$$( \forall a\in A \setminus \{0\}) ( \exists a'\in A )( aa'=a'a=1).$$
so in that sense the answer to your question is yes. A more complete statement would be given by

> If A is a field and B is a ring and they are isomorphic as rings, then B is a field.

Comment: The terminology "A is isomorphic to B" is well-defined after having specified *what A,B are*. More precisely, *which category they belong to*. If A,B are sets, then it is clear what "A is isomorphic to B" means. If A,B are groups, then it is clear what "A is isomorphic to B" means. Likewise if A,B are rings. When one doesn't confuse a ring with its *underlying additive group*, the notion of "isomorphism" is not overloaded.

Answer (score 3):

If $f:A\stackrel\sim\rightarrow B$ is an isomorphism *of rings with unity* and *A* is a field, then also $B$ is a field.

This is an easy exercise:if $ab=1_A$ then $f(a)f(b)=1_B$, and so on

Answer (score 0):

Let $h:A \to B$ be an isomorphism from $A$ to $B$ which implies that $h$ is $1-1$ and $Onto$ mapping and preserves the operation(s). So $A$ and $B$ are of the same sizes and having same behavior with respect to the operation(s).

So if either $A$ or $B$ is field, then the other is also a field.